# Linq query takes so much time according to postgresql

Tags: c#, linq

This query takes 45ms on postgresql

```
  select buf."Platform", buf."id", buf."idc" 
    from dbo."tableA" as buf
    inner join dbo."TableB" as c 
        on c."idc" = buf."idc"::bigint
    inner join dbo."TableC" as o 
        ON o."idc" = c."idc" and  o."id" = buf."id"::bigint and o."idc" = buf."idc"::bigint
group by buf."Platform", buf."id", buf."idc"
```

however, when i write this with linq, it takes almos 1 sec. Why it takes so long ? how can i handle this

```
var List= (from buf in db.TableA
           join c in db.TableB on buf.idc equals c.idc.ToString()
           join o in db.TableC on new { x = c.idc, y = buf.idc, z = buf.id } equals new { x = o.idc, y = o.idc.ToString(), z = o.id.ToString() }                               
           group new { buf } by new { buf.Platform, buf.id, buf.idc} into grp
           select new
           {
               id= grp.Key.id,
               idc= grp.Key.idc,
               platform = grp.Key.Platform,
               count = grp.Count(),
           }
    ).ToList();
```

Comment: Did you look at the query plan of both queries? The query plan will reveal what's going on. My guess is it's something to do with creating those anonymous types to do your joins.... Also you are grouping in one query and not the other

Comment: Well, you are comparing apples and oranges, one query is just using INNER JOINS and the LINQ query is doing joins and also groups by anonymous types. Maybe you need a [multi-column index](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-indexes/postgresql-multicolumn-indexes/) on the group by columns.

Comment: what should  i do ? @TimSchmelter

Comment: @Charleh yes i edit now, actually two of them grouping

Comment: @TimSchmelter linq  join ist same postgresql inner join ? i think they are same

Comment: @hakan: You can use a LINQ `Join` to make an OUTER JOIN as well, but in this case it's same.

Comment: The LINQ query has Count, the SQL query not. Compare the same things. And what exactly takes 1s? Running the query from a cold start? Be more specific.

Comment: @GertArnold it is not about count. problem is , if i use TableC it takes 1 sec in linq, if i dont, it takes 40ms.  TableC is too big . Any advice ?